# How to display a Bitmap Windows zoom level (DPI?) independent in WPF

Tags: wpf, bitmap, zooming, dpi

I am new to WPF, and facing to the following issue.
I am displaying a bitmap, xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyEditorImageTemplate">
    <Image  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3,1,0,0"
            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
            Stretch="None">
        <Image.Source>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyEditorConverter}">
                <Binding Path="....." />
```

The Bitmap is coming from BitmapSource, provided the following way:

```
Bitmap^ bitmap = System::Drawing::Image::FromHbitmap((IntPtr)aBmp);
IntPtr hbmp = bitmap->GetHbitmap();
BitmapSource bs = 
     Imaging::CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbmp, 
                                            System::IntPtr::Zero,
                                            Int32Rect(0,0,nWidth,nHeight),
                                            BitmapSizeOptions::FromEmptyOptions());
```

Now this works fine, until I have the windows zoom level at 100%.
If I change it in Windows to 125%: [image]

The bitmap is also zoomed on the GUI.
[image]

I understand that this is -sort of- the expected, but is there any way that I still show it 1-1 pixel size, ignoring windows zoom settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.
You just need an own Image class, derived from Image, and simple override the OnRender, where you take care of the proper resizing (if necessary).

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    //base.OnRender(dc);    --> we do out own painting
    Rect targetRect = new Rect(RenderSize);
    PresentationSource ps = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
    if (ps != null && Source != null)
    {
        Matrix fromDevice = ps.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
        Vector currentVisibleSize = new Vector(Source.Width, Source.Height);
        Vector originalRestoredSize = fromDevice.Transform(currentVisibleSize);
        targetRect = new Rect(new Size(originalRestoredSize.X, originalRestoredSize.Y));
    }
    dc.DrawImage(Source, targetRect);
}
```

With this, regardless of the Windows zoom setting, you will have always the 100% original size.
I got the idea from this site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx